# Return null if array element does not exist

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, nullable

Is there a simple^ way of getting the value 'null' if an array element does not exist?

For example, in the code below `sArray` has 3 elements and the first 3 calls to `SomeMethod` work (prints true), however the 4th call `SomeMethod(sArray[3]);` gives me an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Is there a way to make the 4th call to `SomeMethod` print false?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] sArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
        SomeMethod(sArray[0]);
        SomeMethod(sArray[1]);
        SomeMethod(sArray[2]);
        SomeMethod(sArray[3]);
    }
    static void SomeMethod(int? s) => Console.WriteLine(s.HasValue);
```

^Would prefer single line expression

Comment: You can prevent from exception then why you need this  type solution you can call somemethod over loop through sArray it will not throw exception

Comment: Downvoted: This appears to be a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).

Comment: Arrays in C# have a `.Length` property which you can check before calling `SomeMethod`. The typical approach is to loop through each element of the array rather than guessing whether or not an index is valid: `for (int i = 0; i < sArray.Length; i++) { SomeMethod(sArray[i]); }`

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don’t agree, I can’t post the actual code as its confidential, I asked the question in the most generalised way I can and in a way that would be more beneficial to readers in the future instead of getting bogged down into the specifics of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SomeMethod(sArray.Skip(3).Select(z => (int?)z).FirstOrDefault());
```

is a working replacement of:

```
SomeMethod(sArray[3]);
```

The former will call `SomeMethod` with `null` (while the latter will throw an exception if the array doesn't have at least 4 entries).

*In `Skip(3)` the 3 can be changed to whatever index you want to retrieve from the array. The `Select` is needed to project the `int` into a `int?` so that `FirstOrDefault` returns either the 4th element **or** `null`.*

If you don't want to use LINQ then you could use:

```
SomeMethod(sArray.Length > 3 ? sArray[3] : (int?)null);
```

instead.

Or consider using:

```
foreach (var entry in sArray.Take(4))
{
    SomeMethod(entry);
}
```

to loop through **up to** 4 elements of the array (it will work fine if there are fewer than 4 - it will just make fewer calls to `SomeMethod`).

Comment: I've used the non-LINQ method in your post as its the most efficient

Answer (score 6):

There is a Linq method [ElementAtOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ElementAtOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Int32_)

To use it the way you want to (returning `null`) you will need ti change the underlying type of your array to nullable int:

```
    int?[] sArray = new int?[]{1,2,3};
    SomeMethod(sArray.ElementAtOrDefault(1000));
```

Comment: This would also work in my case however i decided to go with mjwills's answer as its more efficient

Comment: foreach is the way to go, yes :)

Answer (score 5):

How about an extension method?

```
public static T? TryGet<T>(this T[] source, int index) where T: struct
{
    if (0 <= index && index < source.Length)
    {
        return source[index];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you could write:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] sArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
    SomeMethod(sArray.TryGet(0));
    SomeMethod(sArray.TryGet(1));
    SomeMethod(sArray.TryGet(2));
    SomeMethod(sArray.TryGet(3));
}
```

Comment: This would also work in my case however i decided to go with mjwills's answer as its more efficient.

Comment: I hope you're referring to his non-LINQ answer because the LINQ version is quite expensive (it's O(n) for an array access and creates three auxiliary objects).

Comment: Yes, his non-LINQ answer

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C# have a `.Length` property which you can check before trying to pass an item from one to `SomeMethod`, and the typical approach is to loop through each element of the array rather than guessing whether or not an index is valid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sArray.Length; i++) 
{
    SomeMethod(sArray[i]); 
}
```

You will not be able to avoid an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you reference an index in an array that doesn't exist.

---

However, if you really want a method with this type of functionality, you could simply modify your existing code to check whether or not the index specified is greater than the length of the array.

Since your array is an `int[]` (and not an `int?[]`), all valid indexes will have a value. Also, we can use the `?.` to handle cases where the array itself may be `null`:

```
private static void SomeMethod(int[] array, int index) => 
    Console.WriteLine(index >= 0 && index < array?.Length);
```

Then in use, instead of passing an array item with an invalid index (which will always throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`), you would pass the array itself and the index separately:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] sArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    SomeMethod(sArray, 0);
    SomeMethod(sArray, 1);
    SomeMethod(sArray, 2);
    SomeMethod(sArray, 3);
    SomeMethod(null, 0);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nPress any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This looks like the most sensible approach, and bringing some rationality back to the question. Upvote

Comment: This approach wouldn’t work for me as I need to pass in multiple elements from the array into a method, i.e. SomeMethod((strin)sArray[0],(int?) sArray[1]). I just made the question more general. This might help other tho.

Answer (score -1):

in this case I'll suggest you to create a extension somewhere in your code like this

```
static class ArrExt
{
    public static int? Get(this int[] arr, int i)
    {
        return (i >= 0 && i < arr.Length) ? arr[i] : default(int?);
    }
}
```

then you can do this

```
int[] sArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
SomeMethod(sArray.Get(0));
SomeMethod(sArray.Get(1));
SomeMethod(sArray.Get(2));
SomeMethod(sArray.Get(3));
```

okay this is not a single line solution I know, but it's easier for both programmer and computer.

Comment: This is locked to int